# Use existing server as DNS/Forwarder to another

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ip

I have a VPS which is host several sites on and my clients domain's point their A record to my servers IP address. I now want to move the sites on to a different server in a different part of the internet which has a new address.

How do i set up the original server to point the domains to the new correct location. I don't want to hassel the 20 clients to change their domain name setups.

Also is it possible to point different domains to different servers and not just one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'redirect' a DNS entry to a different IP address. DNS is designed so that whichever server is authoritative for a particular domain holds the records for that domain.

If you've switched the IP address of the server that is serving requests behind a name that your clients manage, you need to tell them about it. There's no workable alternative.

As for your second question, it doesn't really make sense. You can have as many different DNS records for a particular domain as you like. If you set up several A records for a particular subdomain, e.g. www.example.com, I believe most DNS servers will serve them up sequentially in a round-robin way.